# Can't perform POST requests in Laravel test for API routes

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am writing Feature Tests for my Laravel Application, where I perform some requests to my service.

While trying to test my API, all GET requests work fine, but all POST requests return this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://localhost'" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost</title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

My test code looks like this:

```
$this->post('api/my/route')->dump();
```

and my api routes look like this:

```
Route::prefix('my')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/route', function() {
        return 'ok';
    });
```

Are there any middleware etc. I might need to change/deactivate before creating a request like this?

These requests work fine when using the `web.php` routes

Comment: which response are you getting after request?
can u show response?

Comment: Did you tried with `$this->postJson('api/my/route')`?

Comment: @mare96 Thank you! postJson seems to do the trick, even though I am not returning JSON from my route

Comment: @topiji You are welcome. I added an answer to be more precise.

Comment: @topiji Did you know (I certainly didn't) that for language specification in code blocks you have to do a lowercase `\`\`\`html` (not `\`\`\`HTML`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Deepesh Thapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3584034/deepesh-thapa) mentioned, you should return JSON.

And in your test, you should add `postJson` like this:

```
$this->postJson('api/my/route')
```

Go through the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#testing-json-apis).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return a json response. The json method will automatically set the Content-Type header to application/json, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the json_encode PHP function:

So you should indeed return data as below.

```
Route::prefix('my')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/route', function() {
        return response()->json(['message'=>'ok']);
    });
```